# Moq: How to test a class using Nunit with an internal HttpClient?

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, moq

I run my tests inside nUnit and normally I can mock out dependencies and have then Return certain values or throw errors.

I have a class that as an internal HttpClient and I would like to test the class, what are my options.

here is my code, its not complete so as not to flood the message. As you can see I am using the HttpClient internally and not injected as a dependency. The class throws a number of custom exceptions, I would like to Moq these otherwise I need to pass REAL username and passwords that would give me the status codes i required to throw the exceptions.

Anyone have an ideas? If I can't mock the httpclient then i can never test my class that it raises exceptions.

Do I really have to change HttpClient to a dependency on the constructor ?

```
public bool ItemsExist(string itemValue)
{

    var relativeUri = string.Format(UrlFormatString, itemValue.ToUpper());

    var uri = new Uri(new Uri(this.baseUrl), relativeUri);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", this.encodedCredentials);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;

        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                // DO something here
                throw new CustomAuthorizationException();

            case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                throw new CustomAuthenticationException();

        }

        return true;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't unit test it like that. It's like you mentioned: HttpClient is a dependency, and as such, it should be injected.

Personally, I would create my own `IHttpClient` interface, implemented by `HttpClientWrapper`, which wraps around the `System.Net.HttpClient`. `IHttpClient` would then be passed as a dependency to your object's contructor.

As follows, `HttpClientWrapper` can't be unit tested. I would, however, write a couple of integration tests to make sure the wrapper is well written.

**Edit**:

`IHttpClient` doesn't have to be a "valid" interface for `HttpClient`. It only has to be an interface that suits your needs. It can have as many **or** as few methods as you want.

Picture this: HttpClient allows you to do many things. But in your project, you're only calling the `GetAsync(uri).Result` method, nothing else.

Given this scenario, you would write the following interface and implementation:

```
interface IHttpClient
{
    HttpResponseMessage Get(string uri);
}

class HttpClientWrapper : IHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public HttpClientWrapper(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }


    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string uri)
    {
        return _client.GetAsync(new Uri(uri)).Result;
    }
}
```

So, as I stated previously, the interface only has to suit your needs. You don't have to wrap around the *WHOLE* HttpClient class.

Obviously, you would then moq your object like this:

```
var clientMock = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
//setup mock
var myobj = new MyClass(clientMock.object);
```

And to create an actual object:

```
var client = new HttpClientWrapper(new HttpClient());
var myobj = new MyClass(client );
```

**Edit2**

OH! And don't forget that `IHttpClient` should also extend the `IDisposable` interface, very important!

Comment: Sounds good, but IHttpClient, How would I ensure I create a valid Interface for HttpClient...  an Interface can't inherit from a HttpClient... Do I need to create Interface manually ?

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: That is great, I ended up implementing all members in the wrapper. Thanks for the info.

Comment: This seems like an incomplete solution to me. The problem is that in the question the HttpClient gets new-ed up inside a method, which means a new one is needed every time. Therefore, injecting a wrapper which provides a single HttpClient also inside it's constructor is treating the HttpClient as a singleton, which is incorrect. In order to provide a per-instance HttpClient I think we need to inject something like a factory which creates HttpClients (or IHttpClient) on request.

Comment: @RobertNoack Correct, my solution is slightly different than the original code, but it does illustrate my point. You should inject an `IHttpFactory` which returns instances of `IHttpClient`. Moreover, if using DI containers such as Castle Windsor, you usually get these factories for free - you just write the factory's interface, and Castle will generate a type that implements that interface at runtime.

Comment: HttpClient does not need to be disposed according to its developers even though it implements the IDisposable interface. So you don't need the IDisposable.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed "according to its developers" - can you please post your source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed

Answer (score 23):

Let me suggest a bit easier solution, without a need to abstract/wrap httpclient, that i believe works perfectly with mocking frameworks.

You need to create a class for fake HttpMessageHandler, like here:

```
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Send(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Rember to setup this method with your mocking framework");
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Send(request));
    }
}
```

Such created HttpMessageHandler can be used when instantiating HttpClient:

```
var msgHandler = new Mock<FakeHttpMessageHandler>() { CallBase = true };
var fakeclient = new HttpClient(msgHandler.Object);
```

And you can setup methods (here using Moq):

```
msgHandler.Setup(t => t.Send(It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(
            msg =>
                    msg.Method == HttpMethod.Post &&
                    msg.RequestUri.ToString() == "http://test.te/item/123")))
                    .Returns(new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
```

You can now user fakeclient instead when necessary.

Comment: For other's trying this answer: Don't miss setting `CallBase = true`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) [disclosure: I'm the author], a library for building and calling URLs. It includes [testing helpers](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/testable-http/) that make faking all HTTP incredibly easy. No need for wrapper interfaces.

For starters, your HTTP code itself would look something like this:

```
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;

...

try {
    var response = this.baseUrl
        .AppendPathSegment(relativeUri)
        .WithBasicAuth(username, password)
        .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .GetAsync().Result;

    return true;
}
catch (FlurlHttpException ex) {
    // Flurl throws on unsuccessful responses. Null-check ex.Response,
    // then do your switch on ex.Response.StatusCode.
}
```

Now for the testing fun:

```
using Flurl.Http.Testing;

...

[Test]
public void ItemsExists_SuccessResponse() {
    // kick Flurl into test mode - all HTTP calls will be faked and recorded
    using (var httpTest = new HttpTest()) {
        // arrange
        test.RespondWith(200, "{status:'ok'}");
        // act
        sut.ItemExists("blah");
        // assert
        test.ShouldHaveCalled("http://your-url/*");
    }
}
```

Get it on NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package Flurl.Http
```