# Weird behavior of HttpClient uploading file via PostAsync

Tags: c#, post, upload, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

I hope someone has an explanation to this, because it drives me nuts.

I have the following code in a WinForms application to upload a file using HttpClient to a Web API service.

```
ProgressMessageHandler progressMsgHandler = new ProgressMessageHandler();
progressMsgHandler.HttpSendProgress += (s, e) =>
{
   this.InvokeIfNeeded(() =>
   {
      // LOG
      this.AddLogLine("Progress: " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());
    });
};

using (var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(progressMsgHandler))
{ 
   using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
   {
      var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
      var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
      content.Add(streamContent);

      var url = String.Format("{0}?src={1}", STR_URL_FILEMGMT, "IM");
      client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content).ContinueWith(task =>
      {
        if (task.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
            this.InvokeIfNeeded(() =>
            {
               // LOG
               this.AddLogLine("File has been uploaded OK!");
            });
         }
         else
            this.InvokeIfNeeded(() =>
            {
               // LOG
               this.AddLogLine(String.Format("Error during upload: '{0}'", task.Exception.Message));
            });                                
      });
   }
}
```

Please note, entire code listed is also wrapped into a try catch where exception would be printed, if any.

Very weird to me is that I don't get any log line printed at all. Neither for progress, neither for posting with success, neither for posting with errors nor in the global try catch.

During debug, I see the code executing, but doesn't hit any breakpoints where the log lines are.

Probably I don't use correctly HttpClient or these tasks (I am beginner at this btw)? Does anyone know what's going wrong with my code?

---

**UPDATE** (after getting the solution from Noseratio):

Extra information which helps me understand that HttpClient does not need to be disposed can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `client.PostAsync` returns instantly (while the operation continues in the background). This unwinds both of your `using` statements, so the `HttpClient` object gets disposed of **before** the upload has finished.

If you want to utilize `using` here, you'd need to use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`:

```
var result = await client.PostAsync(...);
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you need to target .NET 4.0 but develop with VS2012+ , you still can use `async/await`, Microsoft provides the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) library for that.

Comment: This is of great value. Btw, I am using VS2010, so I want to avoid async/await for now. Could you offer me some hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed, this link says the same: http://forums.asp.net/t/1775726.aspx ... I guess I have to find a way to dispose it in a good way now

Comment: @Cristi,you won't be able to benefit from `using` without `await`, but you can use some handy composition patterns: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx

Comment: Very useful, thanks. For now I removed the using clause, and strangely I got the same behavior. Maybe is because the second using. I have to make more tests..

Comment: Yes, it is most likely the othet `using` which destroys the ` content` object.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Though I noticed another trouble: for ~1Gb file it just stuck at ~4%... again without any error...

Comment: @Cristi, IMO, 1GB is the way to much for a single HTTP upload. You should upload it chunk by chunk and then re-assemble on the server.

Comment: I think I should go for HttpWebRequest

Comment: @Cristi, in my experience `HttpClient` is more robust than `HttpWebRequest`, but I don't think it's a limitation of the client stack. Just imagine what happens if you have a disconnect during a 1GB upload. This could be very frustrating for the user.

Comment: 4% from 1Gb. Only after 40Mb it broke (on my local machine). Not sure if I should call this "robust". Anyway... your idea is not bad, but I don't think is applicable for me. I have special files which I want to transfer, cannot see how to handle the process if I split them up.

Comment: @Cristi, are you using the latest [HTTP Client Libraries 2.2.18](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)? Otherwise, it could be some other bug in your logic, I'd strongly be inclined to think so.

Comment: just so you know: "This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010..." - thanks for helping me out. I think your idea of re-assembling on server is very good, it requires a bit more work, but should be feasible.

Comment: since HttpClient is more for 4.5 and VS2012+ I would stick to the standard HttpWebRequest. I used WebClient earlier, it worked perfect for files up to 1Gb.

Comment: Indeed I missed that :) You do need to use `HttpWebRequest` with VS2010. `HttpClient` would work for .NET 4.0 with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`, but VS2012+ would still be required as development environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, very much appreciated!