# GetStringAsync with ContinueWith and WhenAll -- Not Waiting for all requests to finish

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to process each individual request as it finishes, which is what would happen in the `ContinueWith` after the `GetStringAsync` and then when they've all completed have an additional bit of processing.

However, it seems that the `ContinueWith` on the `WhenAll` fires right away. It appears as if the `GetStringAsync` tasks are faulting, but I can't figure out why.

When I use `WaitAll` instead of `WhenAll` and just add my processing after the `WaitAll` then my requests work just fine. But when I change it to `WhenAll` it fails.

Here is an example of my code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    Task.WhenAll(services.Select(x =>
    {
        return client.GetStringAsync(x.Url).ContinueWith(response =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

    }).ToArray())
    .ContinueWith(response => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `ContinueWith` and `TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent` when using `async-await`. Use `async-await` only, instead:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<string>> SomeMethod(...)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var ss = await Task.WhenAll(services.Select(async x =>
        {
            var s = await client.GetStringAsync(x.Url);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            return s;
        };
        Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
        return ss;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to give this a try. I'm a little new to doing things with `Tasks` so, it's always good to learn the more correct way of doing things. Thanks.

Comment: There, seems to be something off here in your example. You have it with `return s` but if you're awaiting it, isn't `s` a `string` not a `Task`? Also, `ss` would be out of scope since it's inside the `using` block.

Comment: @njkremer `async` methods always return the result of the task, not a task itself.  As for `ss` being out of scope, yes, it is, but you can and should, just move it into the `using`  There's no reason for it to be outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the issue. I'll leave it here in case anyone else comes along looking for a similar answer. I still needed to `await` the `Task.WhenAll` method.

So, the correct code would be:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    await Task.WhenAll(services.Select(x =>
    {
        return client.GetStringAsync(x.Url).ContinueWith(response =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

    }).ToArray())
    .ContinueWith(response => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
    });
}
```

Comment: That's because the using statement disposes your HttpClient which causes the request to be cancelled.  If you get rid of that Using block and make sure the httpClient hangs around then your request will complete correctly.

Comment: You're not actually awaiting `WhenAll`, you're awaiting the `ContinueWith` called on `WhenAll`.  You probably *should* just be awaiting `WhenAll`. It'd clean up your code.

Answer (score 0):

I still see a couple issues with your solution:

1. Drop the using statement - [you don't want to dispose HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15708633/62600).
2. Drop the `ContinueWith`s - you don't need them if your are using `await` properly.
3. The `Task.WhenAny` approach described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx) is a somewhat cleaner way to process tasks as they complete.

I would re-write your example like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var tasks = services.Select(x => client.GetStringAsync(x.Url)).ToList();
while (tasks.Count > 0)
{
    var firstDone = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    tasks.Remove(firstDone);
    Console.WriteLine(await firstDone);
}
Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
```

### *Edit to address comment:*

If you need access to the `service` object as the tasks complete, one way would be to modify `tasks` to be a list of `Task<ObjectWithMoreData>` instead of `Task<string>`. Notice the lambda is marked `async` so we can `await` within it:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var tasks = services.Select(async x => new 
{
    Service = x,
    ResponseText = await client.GetStringAsync(x.Url)
}).ToList();

while (tasks.Count > 0) 
{
    var firstDone = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    tasks.Remove(firstDone);
    var result = await firstDone;
    Console.WriteLine(result.ResponseText);
    // do something with result.Service
}
Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
```

Comment: I like this example, but I am wondering, what if I wanted to do something with the `service` object when the `GetStringAsync` returned in the `services` collection? (The `x` in the lambda)

Comment: Modified answer to provide a possible solution to your comment.