# Async call with HttpClient in PCL

Tags: c#, asynchronous, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient

I have a PCl in which I want to make a async call usingg HttpClient. I coded like this

```
 public static async Task<string> GetRequest(string url)
    {            
        var httpClient = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue };
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

But await is showing error "cannot await System.net.http.httpresponsemessage" like message.

If I use code like this than everything goes well but not in async way

```
public static string GetRequest(string url)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue };
        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

I just want that this method executes in async way.

This is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "error": a compilation error or a runtime exception? What's the exact error message?

Comment: Please show the *exact* error message. I'm sure it isn't just "cannot await".

Comment: this runs fine in linqpad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the [TAP guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx), don't forget to call `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`, dispose your resources, and replace all `Result`s with `await`s:

```
public static async Task<string> GetRequestAsync(string url)
{            
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue })
  {
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  }
}
```

If your code doesn't need to do anything else, `HttpClient` has a `GetStringAsync` method that does this for you:

```
public static async Task<string> GetRequestAsync(string url)
{            
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue })
    return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

If you share your `HttpClient` instances, this can simplify to:

```
private static readonly HttpClient httpClient =
    new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue };
public static Task<string> GetRequestAsync(string url)
{            
  return httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed).

Comment: @ta.speot.is  When used this way, then yes it should be disposed.  However, creating a new instance for each request is not the optimum way of using HttpClient.

Comment: Updated to properly handle resources.

Comment: @StephenCleary  I am getting same error on using your code, Please check the updated part of question.

Comment: @mayank.karki: Install the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a PCL platform that supports .net4 then I suspect you need to install the Microsoft.bcl.Async nuget.