# Using WebClient in ASP.NET 5

Tags: webclient, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working in the VS15 beta and trying to use WebClient. While System.Net is referenced, and the intellisense suggests the WebClient class is available, on build I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'WebClient' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  MyProj.ASP.NET Core 5.0 HomeController.cs

I am doing the following simplistic code:

```
var client = new System.Net.
var html = client.DownloadString(url);
```

When I go to the definition of Web Client, it shows me the source. Not quite sure what the issue is - is WebClient moved? I am struggling to find the resolution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Not sure about `WebClient`, but you can use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to make web requests as well.

Add these references to the `project.json`:

```
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0"
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-*"
        }
    }
},
```

And then here's how to call it from an MVC 6 action method:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication50.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("MyClient", "1.0"));
            var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com");

            ...

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might recommend adding `using(...) { ... }` for the HttpClient example, so readers don't forget to dispose properly.

Comment: The HttpClient does not need to be disposed of according to it's creators. They do recommend you reuse the HttpClient rather than creating one each time for a request.

Comment: To add references to project.json just use "dnu install System.Net.Http"

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed Could you link where is stated that disposal is not needed? It is a disposable class meaning it uses disposable resources (i.e. network connections) therefore has to be disposed. Reuse doesn't mean disposal is not needed, the two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `WebClient` if you only target full .NET Framework instead of .NET Core by in your `project.json` changing:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

to

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },
```