# What is the correct Ninject scope to use when consuming an async RESTful Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I got an `ObjectDisposedException` from my `Index` controller action when hitting refresh the page (i.e. requesting the page for a second time) and I suspect it's due to my incorrect usage of `InRequestScope` in Ninject.

A bit of background here, I have a `CustomHttpClient` class that wraps an `HttpClient` to send `GET` requests to a ASP.NET Web API:

```
public class CustomHttpClient : ICustomHttpClient
{
    private static readonly HttpMessageHandler HttpMessageHandler = 
        new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };

    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private bool _disposed;

    public CustomHttpClient(string uriString) : this(new Uri(uriString))
    {
    }

    public CustomHttpClient(Uri baseUri)
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler) { BaseAddress = baseUri };
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri)
    {
        return await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
    }
```

}

My ASP.NET MVC controller takes this `CustomHttpClient` as a dependency:

```
public class CustomController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICustomHttpClient _customHttpClient;

    public CustomController(ICustomHttpClient customHttpClient)
    {
        _customHttpClient = customHttpClient;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var response = await _customHttpClient.GetAsync("foo/bar");

        // Deserialize the response and return the view
        return View();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
             return;
        }

        if (_httpClient != null && disposing)
        {
            _httpClient.Dispose();
        }

        _dispoed = true;
    }
}
```

My Ninject bindings:

```
public class CustomNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    Bind<ICustomHttpClient>()
        .To<CustomHttpClient>()
        .InRequestScope() // Should I use InCallScope() or InThreadScope() instead?
        .WithConstructorArgument(typeof(string), "http://foo.com");
}
```

My thinking is the `HttpClient` is already disposed after the request ends but the `async` task has not returned an `HttpResponse` yet, causing the `ObjectDisposedException`, is that correct?

Comment: *My thinking is the HttpClient is already disposed after the request ends but the async task has not returned an HttpResponse yet*. How could the request end before the async task returns? You're awaiting on it, that shouldn't happen. Also, why not use it for the lifetime of application? `HttpClient` shouldn't be disposed per request.

Comment: (1) Is there any reason your Web page cannot call the WebAPI directly through AJAX, or is there any reason that your Controller itself cannot contain the logic that you are now putting in the WebAPI? and (2) Why do you need a fresh WebClient upon every request?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I thought `HttpClient` should be similar to how a EF `DbContext` be used. Most will recommend setting `DbContext` to be `InRequestScope`, is this not the case for `HttpClient`?

Comment: Nope, that is definitely not the case for `HttpClient`. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed) for a broader explanation.

Comment: @RoyDictus, the WebAPI I am calling is an external one and I want to do some additional processing before sending the request to the actual API