# How to close EventSource connection on Firebase server using .NET HttpClient with Firebase REST Streaming API

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, firebase, server-sent-events, rest-firebase

I am using the .NET HttpClient to implement the Firebase Streaming Rest API, which itself is supporting the EventSource/Server-Sent Events protocol.

Documentation for this API is here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-streaming

My implementation shown below works properly to connect to Firebase and get my data, running inside a Windows Service which self-updates its business logic and then calls **GetAndProcessFirebaseHttpResponse** as a new Task every 10 minutes.

The problem is that, when I look in my Firebase Dashboard, the number of concurrent connections increases by 1 every time the Task runs, and I cannot seem to tell Firebase that the connection should be closed on the Firebase side and no further data sent.

Here is a simplified example of my code that I put into a sample app. Every time I call GetAndProcessFirebaseHttpResponse, another concurrent connection increments on my Firebase dashboard, and that connection persists even after I cancel the task (via CancellationSourceToken.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()):

```
    public void GetAndProcessFirebaseHttpResponse(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = ListenAsync().Result;

        using (httpResponse)
        {
            using (Stream contentStream = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
            {
                using (StreamReader contentStreamReader = new StreamReader(contentStream))
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            httpResponse.RequestMessage.Dispose();
                        }

                        cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                        string read = contentStreamReader.ReadLineAsync().Result;

                        // Process the data here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ListenAsync()
    {
        // Create HTTP Client which will allow auto redirect as required by Firebase
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler, true);
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_firebasePath);
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

        string requestUrl = _firebasePath + ".json?auth=" + _authSecret;
        Uri requestUri = new Uri(requestUrl);

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/event-stream"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return response;
    }
```

The HttpResponseMessage, Stream, StreamReader, HttpRequestMessage are all disposed. HttpClient is not, because it is recommended that it does not need to be (see, [Do HttpClient and HttpClientHandler have to be disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed)). These disposals naturally release resources on the **client**, however I would guess that they communicate nothing to the **Firebase server** about the need to close the connection on the Firebase end.

My question is: using the .NET HttpClient with the Firebase REST Streaming API, how can I communicate to the Firebase REST endpoint that I am done with the connection and that it should be closed on the Firebase side?

Comment: Answering my own question: sending another HTTP request from the same HttpClient, using a header of "text/html" instead of "text/event-stream", seemed to cause Firebase to decrement the connection count.