# Xamarin HttpClient Request-Timeout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin.Forms application I try to connect to the Exosites api (which is not part of the project so I can't change that one so SignalR or so).

It all works fine for "normal" requests.

The api also supports long polling requests - in the [manual](http://docs.exosite.com/http/#long-polling) it says that the client has to set the header "Request-Timeout" to the request.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);
request.Headers.Add("Request-Timeout", "10000");
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

But doing so, I don't get any answer back, even if i set the timeout to a very small value like 1 (ms). If I set a timeout on a request to another endpoint on Exosites which does not check on it it works fine. Sending the exact same request without the "Request-Timeout" header also works fine.

Does anyone have experience with long polling calls in Xamarin using HttpClient?

Thanks a lot!

tschuege

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out that "Request-Timeout" is not a standard header. It's a custom header Exosite uses to distinguish long polls from normal calls.

The problem I had was not related to that. I used fiddler to capture a long poll to the Exosite api made using postman. After the time defined with "Request-Timeout" passed by the response returned and Fiddler showed the following protocol violation:

> Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 27 bytes, but server sent 0 bytes.

So the problem was that HttpClient was not able to process the response. Fortunately `SendAsync` has an overload accepting an additional parameter of type `HttpCompletionOption` that has the following description on msdn:

> Indicates if HttpClient operations should be considered completed either as soon as a response is available, or after reading the entire response message including the content.

Using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` the call gets back before the response is read which worked like a charm in my case.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it's a lot easier than that.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeoutSeconds);
}
```

PS: Be sure to always wrap your `new  HttpClient()` in a `using` block.

Comment: Thanks. As I understand it client.Timeout is something different - something HttpClient internal. I see it is a timer that starts when sending the request and if it runs out before the request returns the caller gets notified. The server does participate on that. The header "Request-Timeout" on the other hand is sent to the server. In the Exosites case the server does then not answer immediately and waits until something changes or the time runs out. I tried it with client.Timeout and got an answer immediately even though there were no changes - so it was no long poll.

Comment: It's not good reason to dispose every time HttpClient. It's common mistake a lot of people http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed