# Why is this HttpClient usage giving me an "Cannot access a disposed object." error?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I've simplified the code a bit but basically this keep giving me a "Cannot access a disposed object." error and I cant work out why?

I have multiple tasks running simultaneously that perform a GET then parse some HTML then perform a POST depending on the results of the GET.

The method this code resides in returns an event object with results so I don't think I can use await because the method would need to return void?

```
foreach (Account accountToCheck in eventToCheck.accountsToRunOn)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "false");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://test.com", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).Result;
            string html = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test[username_or_email]",  accountToLogIn.accountHandle),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test[password]",           accountToLogIn.accountPassword)
            });

            var loginPostResult = client.PostAsync("https://test.com/login", content).Result;

            loginHTMl = convertToUTF8(loginPostResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
    });
}
```

Exception.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: Cannot access a disposed object.

Comment: Which line is giveing you that exception? Post the entire stack trace in your question.

Comment: Can you post the actual stack trace of the exception that you are seeing.,

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully that helps a little, let me know what else I can add :-)

Comment: I think, it is just, because You ran out of scope of Your using, after ReadStringAsync returns. So the loginPostresult is disposed automatically, because of the using directive.

Comment: In your actual running code is loginPostResult and the convertToUTF8 inside or outside of the Using block?

Comment: CathalMF: just count the braces :-D

Comment: @icbytes He said he simplified the code. The code posted is not what he is running.

Comment: @jamie Remove the using block and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Note that this might be one of the few exceptions where the using / dispose pattern isn't best practice - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Ok after a bit of research i found the issue. The HttpClientHandler will get disposed after the first request. You need to instruct your system not to dispose the handler.

Change your using to add `false` to the constructor.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, false))
{

}
```

Comment: Weird, I set this but it doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: You need to call ReadAsByteArrayAsync between "using"

Comment: Do not use `HttpClient` in a using statement. https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @SamRueby and comment author so the best idea is to not use using or to prevent the handler for disposing?

Comment: @CDrosos as the linked article suggests, it's best to make your `HttpClient` static and to not explicitly dispose.

Answer (score 9):

It's a good practice to reuse HttpClientHandler instance to prevent disposing.

Also personally I prefer more clear syntax with minimizing Task.Result calls.

```
// single setup of client handler
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

var tasks = eventToCheck.accountsToRunOn.Select(async () => {
    // ...
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, false)) // pass false to prevent Disposing
    {
        // ...
        var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // ...
        return loginHtml;
    }
});

// get array of results
string[] loginsHtml = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 6 and Dependency Injection, make sure `AddScoped` line is before the `AddHttpClient` line. Example:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService, Service>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IService, Service>();
```

Doing the other way around causes the `cannot-access-a-disposed-object` issue.

Answer (score 0):

If we are using containers for injecting the Dependency of HttpClient, then "using" is not required. The container will manage the life time by itself

Answer (score 0):

Another case I encountered is when operating an Azure Function. When the timeout expires, you get such a message for whatever service you are using.