# System.ObjectDisposedException on Subsequent Calls to an Async File Processing Method in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm encountering a System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. error when making subsequent calls to an asynchronous method designed to process uploaded files in an ASP.NET Core application. The method works fine on the first call, but throws the error on any follow-up attempts.

The method in question, ProcessFileAsync, accepts an IFormFile and an API URL. It uses HttpClient provided by IHttpClientFactory for making an HTTP POST request to the specified API URL, with the file content included in the request. The method is intended to run tasks in the background and immediately return a task ID.

Here's a simplified version of the method's structure:

```
private Task<string> ProcessFileAsync(IFormFile file, string apiUrl)
{
    // Generate a new task ID and add to a tracking dictionary
    string taskId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    _tasksStatus.TryAdd(taskId, "Processing");

    // Run the processing logic in a background task
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            using var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            // Configure client and prepare the request content using the file stream
            // Make the HTTP POST request
            // Handle the response
            _tasksStatus[taskId] = "Completed";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _tasksStatus[taskId] = "Error";
        }
    });

    return Task.FromResult(taskId);
}
```

The error occurs when attempting to read from the file stream passed to the HttpClient. The first call processes successfully, indicating that resources and logic flow as expected initially. However, any subsequent calls result in the ObjectDisposedException error, pointing to a problem with accessing a closed file stream.

Here are the key points:

The error specifically mentions "Cannot access a closed file."
The issue only arises on subsequent calls to the function, not the first one.
The application is structured to handle file uploads and process them asynchronously.
Given this, how can I ensure that each call to ProcessFileAsync can execute independently without encountering disposed object issues? Is there a specific pattern or best practice in ASP.NET Core for resetting or properly managing resources in such asynchronous, repeated operations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use brace with "using" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using

```
            using (var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
            {
                // Configure client and prepare the request content using the file stream
                // Make the HTTP POST request
                // Handle the response
            }
            _tasksStatus[taskId] = "Completed";
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I try it and have the same error

Comment: @ClashSecondo I suggest you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36699341/20240963 and use httpclient instead to see if the problem replicates.