# curl post Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, post, curl, xamarin

How do I do something simple as :

```
curl -X POST --data-binary '{"a":"b"}' --location "$URL"
```

I am working on Xamarin, c#

I am having problems with the dependecies.

Comment: Why don't you use HttpClient ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could use `HttpClient` by adding a system reference to `System.Net.Http`.  Use the following sample code to create a client and submit the same call.  Note that you could use another framework for converting class types into JSON text like Json.NET. Note that the following example shows how to construct `HttpClient`, but you should [not dispose of the instance and track it elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15708633/4027768).

```cs
var client = new HttpClient()

string content = "{\"a\":\"b\"}";
StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(content);

var response = await client.PostAsync("$URL", httpContent);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // Show response. 
}
else
{
    // Show error.
}
```