# UWP - How can i get a file (xml) from http?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have this code to load the xml (to a List) and it works fine:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    string XMLFilePath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "something.xml");
    XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(XMLFilePath);
}
```

what if I want to call the xml from my server!?

This is the last try:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
```

...

```
private string jsonString;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        loadData();

        //string XMLFilePath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "something.xml");
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(jsonString);
```

...

```
private async void loadData()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://domain.com/something.xml"));
        jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

this is the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: what is now working for you edit your question and explain it `It's not Working` does not provide anyone any useful information where does the xml file reside..?

Comment: Is it explicit now @MethodMan ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync | loadFromUriAsync methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to asynchronously loads an XML document from the specified location. This location can also be a Http link.

Just for a very simple test here:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txt" />
```

code behind:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(new Uri("http://domain.com/something.xml"));
    txt.Text = xmlDoc.GetXml().ToString();
}
```

Just be noticed that the namespace for xml document here is `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom`, not `System.Xml`. And I noticed that your Uri address is like `http://domain.com/something.xml`, maybe you are using the native server, when doing this, you may probably need to enable the `Private Networks(Client & Server)` capability in your project's manifest file.

**Update**:

Sorry I didn't know you want to use `LinQ`, to use `XDocument` to load xml, there are basically two methods: from string Uri or from stream, but for the first method, the Uri parameter must be a file system relative or absolute path.

So, here one method is you can save the xml to local file and load it again with `XDocument`, or you can use stream to achieve this, for example:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://domain.com/something.xml");
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(response);
txt.Text = xmlDoc.Document.ToString();
```

Comment: That example works with my xml link, thanks; But i'm using linq, how can I achieve that with XDocument instead!?

Comment: You should wrap `HttpClient()` with `using`: `using (var client = new HttpClient()) { /*your code */ }`

Comment: @aloisdg, I can understand you want to dispose this `HttpClient` by warping the code with `using`, but there is no "should". You can refer to [Do HttpClient and HttpClientHandler have to be disposed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed)

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I know but here i guessed that OP is going to put it inside a method and call the method each time, creating a new client each time. I put my client outside of the method and don't use using myself for the reason written in this SO post (especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed#comment40535896_15708633).

Comment: I think the httpclient version is the better route.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the address, try something like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
this.InitializeComponent();
string XMLFilePath = @"http://www.msn.com";
XmlDocument LoadedData = new XmlDocument();
LoadedData.Load(XMLFilePath);
}
```

If you want to use the XDocument object try to use the method "Parse" instead of "Load".

Comment: Thanks @Dark, already tried that and the last "XMLFilePath" word throw: "(local variable) string XMLFilePath  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'"

Answer (score 0):

Your private async void loadData() is not await and the jsonString is null.
You can

```
private async void loadData()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://domain.com/something.xml"));
    jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(jsonString);
}

 public MainPage()
 {
    this.InitializeComponent();

    loadData();
 }
```

Comment: That's what I have!!