# How to write an asynchronous Policy handler, injecting a scoped service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, policy

I'm trying to write a custom policy for an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application, using a custom Identity storage provider.

I've tried to wrap my head around the fact that policies in ASP.NET Core are designed to take user informations from an `HttpContext` object, when I read this in a [MSDN Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/october/cutting-edge-policy-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core):

> once you hold a reference to the user, you can always find the username from the claims and run a query against any database or external service

I started writing my own policy (as of now a simple role requirement) injecting the `UserManager` into the constructor:

```
public class RoleHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RoleRequirement>
{
    private UserManager<AppUser> UserManager;

    public RoleHandler(UserManager<AppUser> usermanager)
    {
        UserManager = usermanager;
    }
}
```

Now I have a couple problems:

**INJECTING A SCOPED SERVICE IN A SINGLETON**

Policies are supposed to be lasting for the entire application life, so that would be a Singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleHandler>();
```

but the UserManager injected in the policy server is a scoped service and that is not allowed. Solution was very easy, changing the configuration of the policy service from a singleton to a scoped service

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleHandler>();
```

but I don't know whether that cause any issue or not.

**WRITING AN ASYNCHRONOUS POLICY HANDLER**

This is my implementation of the `HandleRequirementAsync` method:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RoleRequirement requirement)
{
    AppUser user = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(context.User.Identity.Name).Result;

    if (user != null)
    {
        bool result = UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, requirement.Role.ToString()).Result;
        if (result) context.Succeed(requirement);
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I used `Task.Result` but it blocks the thread. I can't use `await` because that would make the method returning a `Task<Task>` instead of a `Task` and I can't change it. How can I solve this?

Comment: don't return Task.Completed Task just write like this  await Task.CompletedTask; Why dont u use like this context.User.IsInRole(requirement.Role.ToString())

Comment: @Muhammad Sami context.User doesn’t expose the IsInRole method, that’s a complete different entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't return `Task.CompletedTask`.

When you declare a method as `async`, it *implicitly* returns a `Task` when the first `await` is hit:

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RoleRequirement requirement)
{
    AppUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(context.User.Identity.Name);

    if (user != null)
    {
        bool result = await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, requirement.Role.ToString());
        if (result) context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}
```

`Task.CompletedTask` is generally used when you need to implement a `Task` returning method synchronously, which you are not.

Answer (score 0):

My HandleRequirementAsync also calls httpClient.GetAsync (Blazor server, .NET 5), adding async to the HandleRequirementAsync and execute the await hpptClient.GetAsync() breaks the authorization. With async method with delays, Try typing the route address in the browser and it will redirect to not authorized page, even though the context.Succeed(requirement) is executed.

The working solution for me is to keep the HandleRequirementAsync as it is, returning Task.CompletedTask. For the async method we need to call, just use pattern for calling async method from non async method.

The one I use is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43148321/423356

my sample async method:

```
public async Task<IList<Permission>> GetGroupPermissions(int userId)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format("Auth/GroupPermissions/{0}", userId));

    try
    {
        var payload = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Permission>>();
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return payload;
    }
    catch
    {
        return new List<Permission>();
    }

}
```

HandleRequirementAsync:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)
{
    var t2 = (Task.Run(() => GetGroupPermissions(userId)));
    t2.Wait();
    var userGroupPermissions = t2.Result;
    

    if (!userGroupPermissions.Contains(requirement.Permission))
    {
        //context.Fail(); //no need to fail, other requirement might success
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    context.Succeed(requirement);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```