# Asynchronous operation does not work even though I wrote it with async / await - C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

it's been a while that I try to write asynchronous code in C#, I did it and was sure it is asynchronous, recently I read I checked with postman the time that the function takes to finish when it's Asynchronous and when it's synchronous, and it seems like it takes the SAME time exactly, what I did wrong in my code?

Here is my code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("customerslist")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> getData()
    {
        string url1 = @"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
        string url2 = @"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments";
        string url3 = @"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";

        Task<string> firstTask = myHttpCall(url1);
        Task<string> secondTask = myHttpCall(url2);
        Task<string> thirdTask = myHttpCall(url3);

        await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask, thirdTask);

        var result = firstTask.Result + secondTask.Result + thirdTask.Result;
        return Ok(result);
    }

    private async Task<string> myHttpCall(string path)
    {
        string html = string.Empty;
        string url = path;

        // Simple http call to another URL to receive JSON lists.
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return html;
    }
```

I make HTTP request to another URL to get their JSON lists, anyone can help me please? I will be happy if anyone can tell me how to write it properly.

Comment: Why should the execution time be any different for sync and async?  the amount of code executed is the same especially if you are not running any other code.

Comment: There's also nothing async about the `myHttpCall` method, you're not awaiting anything inside it.

Comment: Indeed, you should be getting a warning about an async method with no await...

Comment: @jdweng: If `myHttpCall` where *really* asynchronous, the three requests would be made in parallel, leading to shorter overall time.

Comment: Please read your compiler warnings. The C# compiler says: "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously."

Comment: it depends on the bandwidth of the channel how much improvement you would have and the response times of the servers.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTTP calls are synchronous. Use HttpClient in your `myHttpCall` method more or less like this:

```
private async Task<string> myHttpCall(string path)
{
    using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
           HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
           return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

EDIT: To add automatic decompression pass following object to `HttpClient` constructor:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
};
```

Comment: While it is definitely non-obvious, `HttpClient` is meant to be re-used, not created and disposed every time. We should try to get out of the habit of recommending this pattern with `HttpClient`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about it. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed)