# Send large file via HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I need to upload large files (~200MB) over HTTP protocol. I want to avoid loading the files to memory and want to send them directly.

Thanks to this [article](https://www.techcoil.com/blog/uploading-large-http-multipart-request-with-system-net-httpwebrequest-in-c/) I was able to make it with `HttpWebRequest`.

```
HttpWebRequest requestToServer = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("....");

requestToServer.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
requestToServer.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
requestToServer.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryString;
requestToServer.KeepAlive = false;
requestToServer.ContentLength = ......;

using (Stream stream = requestToServer.GetRequestStream())
{
    // write boundary string, Content-Disposition etc.
    // copy file to stream
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream("...", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        fileStream.CopyTo(stream);
    }

    // add some other file(s)
}
```

However, I would like to do it via `HttpClient`. I found [article](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/streaming-with-newnet-httpclient-and-httpcompletionoption-responseheadersread) which describes using of `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` and I tried something like this but it does not work unfortunately.

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryString);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "close");

    var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "....");

    using (HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        using (Stream stream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            // here I wanted to write content to the stream, but the stream is available only for reading
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I overlooked or missed something...

---

**UPDATE**

On top of it, it is important to use `StreamContent` with proper headers:

- [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)
- [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

Comment: If you have a method that works, why bother?

Comment: fyi comment - I have encountered different behaviors with the objects your are using between full framework and core2.0 and on prem and azure.  You may have to consider your final target environment to feel confident in your final solution.

Comment: You need to read [You are using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: @mason that article is dogma and shouldn't be recommended without changes.

Comment: @CoryNelson What are you talking about? This is a well known issue. You shouldn't create an HttpClient each time you use it. And if you use a singleton, depending on the application, you risk not getting new IP's in the event of DNS changes. That article is absolutely correct, and libraries that build on top of HttpClient [account for it](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/144).

Comment: @CoryNelson Before calling something "dogma" and dismissing it, make sure you've done adequate research. Microsoft has also stated "HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application....Creating a new HttpClient instance per request can exhaust the available sockets." [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client). Also see the relevant [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed).

Comment: @mason slow your role man, you're getting too worked up. The blog post claims that `using(HttpClient)` is wrong and that apps should use a globally reused `HttpClient`, but this is not a change without consequences -- this changes how `HttpClient` behaves. To not address this is a mistake, and to recommend all newbies switch over to this would be to misinform them. That is all I meant.

Comment: Current recommendation is to never depend on HttpClient directly, but to use IHttpClientFactory to get HttpClient objects as needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [`StreamContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.streamcontent.aspx) class:

```
HttpResponseMessage response =
    await httpClient.PostAsync("http://....", new StreamContent(streamToSend));
```

In your example, you are getting a *response* stream and trying to write to it. Instead, you must pass in your content for the *request*, as above.

The `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` is to disable buffering of the response stream, but does not affect the request. You would typically use it if your response is large.

For posting multiple files of form data, use the [`MultipartFormDataContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent.aspx):

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

content.Add(new StreamContent(stream1), "file1.jpg");
content.Add(new StreamContent(stream2), "file2.jpg");

HttpResponseMessage response =
    await httpClient.PostAsync("http://...", content);
```

Comment: It looks promising. What if I need to upload several files in one request (multipart) and want to still avoid loading them to memory?

Comment: I suppose `MultipartFormDataContent`, I feel stupid now that I completely overlooked it.

Comment: Added an example for that one too ;)

Comment: Are those files loaded to memory (buffered) or not? I can see that my app takes huge amount of memory when I send such request.

Comment: I'd be very surprised to hear that they are, but you'd need to take a look at the implementation of `MultipartFormDataContent` to know. `StreamContent` does not buffer.

Comment: I can't get this to send files bigger than 28MB. I keep getting `404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent`

Comment: Will it work for files of larger sizes?  lets say 20 GB..

Comment: I would like to know how to send larger amounts of data as well.  Hitting a limit with 58GB using Nancy.