# Should RestClient be singleton or create new instance for every requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, restsharp

ASP.Net `HttpClient` is disposable, and a lot of articles say you should use the singleton pattern to use it because of the performance. But when I see the `RestClient` it can't be disposed, and in the [Recommended-Usage](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage) page the sample will `new` the `RestClient` every time. Should I use singleton pattern for `RestClient` or should I `new` it every time? If I `new` it every time will there be any performance concern?

[RestSharp GitHub](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp)

Some references:

[Do HttpClient and HttpClientHandler have to be disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

## For Restclient version < 107:

> should I use singleton pattern for RestClient or should I new it
> everytime, if I new it everytime will any performance concern?

Recommended way to use `RestSharp` is to create a new instance per request.

It differs from Singleton approach recommended for `HttpClient`. And the reason is that [under the hood](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/develop/RestSharp/Http.Sync.cs) `RestSharp` uses `HttpWebRequest` for HTTP interaction, not `HttpClient`. That's why the usage model differs.

> If I create it everytime do I get performance issue just like the
> HttpClient?

The main reason why you shouldn't create a new instance of `HttpClient` for each request is not a performance consideration. The time spent for creation and initialization will take a tiny fraction of time spent for following network call. The main reason to use singleton instance of `HttpClient` [is the following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx):

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout
> the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for
> every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy
> loads. This will result in SocketException errors.

`RestSharp` does not use connection pool as `HttpClient` and does not leave opened sockets after the use. That's why it is safe (and recommended) to create a new instance of `RestClient` per request.

Will you gain any performance improvement if you use reuse instance of `RestClient`? Well, you will save the time for creation of object and its initialization. However this time is very close to `0` and moreover it's a tiny fraction of time spent for following network call. You don't reuse other .NET objects like `List<T>` because of performance considerations, are you? You should do the same for `RestClient`. It's just developed in a way that implies such usage scenario.

Comment: If I create it everytime do I get performance issue just like the `HttpClient`?

Comment: I update my post please see the references and I think you are right

Comment: After reading this answer I'm wondering if it would make sense to inject `IRestClient` as a transient to WebApi services?

Comment: Yes, it totally makes sense.

Comment: Not sure if this is accurate anymore, I was about to implement restsharp in a project  but pumped the brakes because it appears to use a new socket on each request, this would likely cause socket exhaustion at any scal. github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1322

Comment: We were using rest sharp and would routinely get socket exception errors using the new each time.

Comment: I agree that the answer is misleading. thanks @StuckOverflow for pointing me to the link. 
I had a back and forth with my team mate about this, who after googling suggested we stick to restsharp. but having read the latest update from restharp on github, i realise that it might not be ideal for apps t hat make several http requests this may not be ideal as instantiating it everytime could lead to socket exhaustion. https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1406 confirms that the dev has plans to do this later but it is opensource after all.

Comment: just to give you further information, HttpWebRequest instantiates HttpClient everytime it is instantiated, leading to the socket exhaustion detailed by microsoft docs. 
Since RestSharp's RestClient, uses HttpWebRequest, instantiating RestClient, multiple times in different parts of the app, would lead to the same socket exhaustion. code can be seen here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/07080ceab1e5b305d8a5fecd9d5b793fb502d57a/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L1101

Comment: HttpWebRequest has GetCachedOrCreateHttpClient function that will use AreParametersAcceptableForCaching to check if HttpClient can be reused

Comment: The pattern changed with version v107 https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107 Do not instantiate the client for a single call, otherwise you get issues with hanging connections and connection pooling won't be possible.

Answer (score 22):

## For Restclient version >= 107:

From version `v107` you should create only one instance. This version is using `HttpClient` internally.

> Do not instantiate RestClient for each HTTP call. RestSharp creates a
> new instance of HttpClient internally, and you will get lots of
> hanging connections, and eventually exhaust the connection pool.
>
> If you use a dependency-injection container, register your API client
> as a singleton.

[RestClient lifecycle](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restclient-lifecycle)

If you are wondering why this is the case, you can see explanation [here](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)