# Moving from RestSharp to HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp

Currently we are using `RestClient` from RestSharp library like below.

```
var client = new RestClient("<some url>");
var request = new RestRequest("", "GET");
request.AddHeader("content-type", RestClientModel.ContentType);
request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", RedirectUrl);
RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
return response;
```

We are facing performance issues while using `RestClient`. That's the reason we want to move to `HttpClient`. So, we need help on the following points.

1. Using `HttpClient` instance in `RestClient` constructor which will be injected in respective class which will configure in startup.cs.
2. What is alternate for `AddParameter` in `HttpClient`? As this doesn't seems to be equivalent to adding headers in `HttpClient`.

Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: `AddParameter` should be referring to querystring parameters.

Comment: What, specifically, are you unsure of on the first point? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests is a good starting point.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior That one of the solution we are thinking by using HttpClient inside RestClient instead of re-writing whole thing again in HttpClient. By doing so, still it will have performance issues?

Comment: It depends on a few things. If your performance issues are from socket exhaustion, and you're using a version of RestSharp that uses HttpClient under the hood, you can probably solve those performance problems either by [using singleton instances of RestClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71413340/120955) or by [injecting HttpClient instances](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#reusing-httpclient) that you get from an IHttpClientFactory, or even by simply [passing `true` as the `useClientFactory` parameter](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#simple-factory) when you create your client.

Answer (score 1):

For `GET` request `AddParameter` adds query string parameter. Quote from [docs](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#query-string):

```cs
var client = new RestClient("https://search.me");
var request = new RestRequest("search")
    .AddParameter("foo", "bar");
var response = await client.GetAsync<SearchResponse>(request);
```

> It will send a GET request to [https://search.me/search?foo=bar"](https://search.me/search?foo=bar%22).

You can try something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = new()
{
    { "redirect_uri", RedirectUrl }
};
var query= await new FormUrlEncodedContent(queryParams).ReadAsStringAsync();

var response = await client.GetAsync($"{someUrl}?{query}")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you inject an `HttpClient` to the `RestClient` then your second question is pointless.

You can use the exact same code to add a parameter. You don't need to port that.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://httpstat.us/") };
var client = new RestClient(httpClient);
var request = new RestRequest("200", Method.Get);
request.AddParameter("delay", "1000");

Console.WriteLine(client.BuildUri(request).AbsoluteUri);
```

This will print: `https://httpstat.us/200?delay=1000`

---

[Dotnet Fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wV1GtB)

Comment: Thanks for quick help. If I use HttpCLient inside RestClient will it solve my socket exhaustion and performance issues? I will be configuring  HttpClient in startup.cs like builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IRestClientService, RestClientService>() and injecting its dependency in RestClientService class and using in subsequent methods wherever RestClient is used.

Comment: @XamDev The `RestClient` is just a thin wrapper around `HttpClient`. With this approach you have more control over the underlying `HttpClient`. If you don't provide an instance then it will create [on your behalf](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/cc44c361d4aa7caa5b868d4440820cd2e382a7ef/src/RestSharp/RestClient.cs#L77)

Comment: Agree. We are seeing issue's while performance test done for concurrent users for RestClient. That's why we are thinking to use HttpClient instance in RestClient the approach which I explained in previous replies.

Comment: @XamDev Quite frankly I don't think that it will solve your socket exhaustion problem but you should give it a try and see how does it behave in the wild :)

Comment: It could solve the socket exhaustion problem if the HttpClient instances are managed correctly. Creating new HttpClients for every call is a known source of socket exhaustion, and newer versions of RestClient use HttpClient and (by default) create a new instance of HttpClient per RestClient instance.