# .NET Core Dispose implementation

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dispose, idisposable

I'm a little confused how to implement Dispose pattern correctly.

I have a class:

```
public class DomainActions : IDomainActions, IDisposable
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public DomainActions(string baseAddress, string token)
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    }

    public async Task<List<DomainDto>> GetDomainListAsync()
    {
        var requestStream = await _client.GetAsync("domains");
        var requestString = await requestStream.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return ParseDomainListResponse(requestString);

    }
```

as I understand, I have to allocate `_client`

```
public class DomainActions : IDomainActions
{
    //...
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private bool _disposed = false;
    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_client != null)
            {
                _client.Dispose();
                _client = null;
            }
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

my implemetation is correct, is it enough?

Comment: Since `_client` is of a type that implements `IDisposable`, you need to call `Dispose` on it before setting it to null

Comment: @vc74, edited, is it right now?

Comment: It looks fine though. You can have a look at msdn guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Comment: you shouldn't need to call `.Dispose` on an `HttpClient`,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed

Comment: @vc74, added one line

Comment: @DanielA.White, thank you!

Comment: @OlegSh I this case I'd definitely dispose of the HttpClient when disposing the instance since it is never going to be used again after disposal (unlike a global client that you could use for subsequent queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing us where you create `_client`, but let's figure out it is done in the constructor.

You are disposing the object correctly. For reference, this is the Visual Studio snippet for a complete disposal:

```
    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls
    
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }
    
    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~A() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
```

If your unmanaged resources do not require special cleanup and can be represented by handles, you should use `SafeHandles` which are less error prone and more concise. For further information, please have a look at [Implement a Dispose Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).

Comment: If you have unmanaged resources: the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) advise to construct System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle objects instead of implementing a finalizer

Comment: That is true if you can collapse your resources by mere handles. There are cases which require you to call additional methods to perform the cleanup. I posted the Dispose pattern to show them how it was supposed to work. I improved the answer. Thank you:)

Comment: Not only does their object not have unmanaged resources that can't be represented by a safe handle, *they don't have any unmanaged resources at all*.  None of this is helpful and is even *detrimental* to include in a situation such as this.