# Calling REST Api return 404 always in asp.net core v2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have `REST Apis` and now I want to call them in `asp.net core` project.
My project is based on `ASP.NET Core V2`.
To do this , I wrote these lines of code :

```
services.AddHttpClient("apiserver")
   .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    return new HttpClientHandler()
   {
       AllowAutoRedirect = false,
       UseDefaultCredentials = true,
       Proxy = new WebProxy
       {
           Address = new Uri("proxyserver:80"),
           Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass",     "domain")
       }
    };
 });


using (var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("apiserver"))
{

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));

    var result = client.GetAsync("http://url/api/user/test/");
    var response = result.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return Ok(result.Result.StatusCode);
}
```

This Code Always Return `404` Error Code(`Not Found`) but when I enter full adreess (`http://url/api/user/test/`) in browser it works fine.

And Also I call the `REST` Address in `Postman`  it works probably and return My expected result.

what is problem whit this?

Comment: I think you shouldn't dispose the httpClient. [Do HttpClient and HttpClientHandler have to be disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15708633/8810910)

Comment: You can also configure the HttpClient in the AddHttpClient Extension method. [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#named-clients)