# "Address in use" error (with C# HttpClient)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code for checking availability applications from play market and app store:

```
public async Task<List<CheckPackageResponse>> CheckAsync(List<string> appIds)
{
    var sem = new SemaphoreSlim(200);

    var tasks = appIds.Select(async (a, i) =>
    {
        await sem.WaitAsync();

        var response = new CheckPackageResponse
        {
            AppId = a,
        };

        string url;

        // if IOS
        if (a.All(Char.IsDigit))
        {
            url = $"https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/id{a}?dataOnly=true&isWebExpV2=true";
        }
        else
        {
            url = $"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={a}";
        }

        try
        {
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36");

            var resp = await _client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            response.HttpStatus = (int) resp.StatusCode;

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
            response.StackTrace = e.StackTrace;

            return response;
        }
        finally
        {
            sem.Release();
        }

    }).ToList();

    return (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).ToList();
}
```

And in the `Startup.cs` I have the following to inject `HttpClient`:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ICheckPackagesService, CheckPackagesService>(x =>
{
    x.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy(Configuration["Proxy"] != "" ? Configuration["Proxy"] : null)
});
```

It works nice. I can give list of application ids and API will answer me is an application available or not. But it has some problem. After some time it has crash with error

> Address in use.

It tells me that HTTP client does not close connections. But I know that this problem possible if I use something like this:

```
using(var http = new HttpClient(...)) {
    ... 
}
```

And it's definitely not my case. 
So what is wrong in my case? Where is the mistake?

### Update

I will pin here my stack trace

> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)\n   at ApChecker.Services.Concrete.CheckPackagesService.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in /builds/mobilemediaru/makeapp/apchecker/ApChecker/Services/Concrete/CheckPackagesService.cs:line 50

Comment: Please check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed

Comment: *After some time* is too broad, can you clarify or provide more information then that? what is the actual exception thrown here? is it a Socket exception? what raises it? what does the stack trace show?

Comment: @BrettCaswell thank you for comment. I have updated me question. But is it useful? I use my http client in the async cosntruction like `appIds.Select(async (a, i) =>
    { ... }`. And it gives me common exception in this case, that tells about canceling operation.

Comment: hmm.. this issue could relate to Socket Port exhaustion... where the cause could relate to initializing new instances of HttpClient (irregardless to the disposal of them).

Comment: But I use only one http client instance, am I right? Via http client factory. Like in this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#implement-your-typed-client-classes-that-use-the-injected-and-configured-httpclient

Comment: *it will receive a new HttpClient instance each time it's constructed* in that link you provided

Comment: Listen guys, in the link that @JayakumarThangavel have pined in the comment above I have found information about sending `Connection : close` HTTP header. Maybe it will solve my problem. What do you think?

Comment: @BrettCaswell hmm, yes, you are right. I thought that It will create only one HTTP client instance for whole application. But now I see that it is false.

Comment: I feel like there is more to this then starving the connection pool though.. the concurrency in this operation along with the retry is a consideration here.  I'm not sure how relevant this [github bug](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37044) issue is but it has me curious if some internals are working correctly here

Comment: I read more of that documentation, you're right.. in fact `HttpMessageHandler` objects are managing the pool of each `HttpClient`, so it doesn't really matter about the initialization of new `HttpClient` as much as the configurable notion on `HttpMessageHandler` lifetimes.

Comment: Last question from me, how many `appIds` records are you running?

Comment: @BrettCaswell just one `app_id`.

Comment: I have added ```Connection: close``` HTTP header, and I have added ```Dispose()``` call for the HTTP client response. I hope it will solve my issue. If it works, I will publish it as answer.