# Necessity of disposable on a while loop

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

This is something that could be really noob, but I really would like to understand. I´m doing a console application that makes a request to Swapi API (the star wars api) and, catch all the starships available on the API.
When I hit their API (https://swapi.co/api/starships), the response return a field called "next", that has the other part of the starships that they have (the API is making the pagination on each request)

Well, I´ve made a class that do the first request to their API, deserialize the object, and inside of a while, I verify if the field "next" is null and do the rest of the requests with the field "next"

This is my code

```
public class RequestToSwapiApi : IRequestToSwapiApi
    {
        private string Json;

        private string ApiURL
        {
            get
            {
                return "https://swapi.co/api/starships/";
            }
        }

        public async Task<RootObject> ReturnTheStarShipModels()
        {
            var request = new HttpClient();
            this.Json = await request.GetStringAsync(this.ApiURL);
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(this.Json);

            while (rootObject.Next != null)
            {
                this.Json = await request.GetStringAsync(rootObject.Next);
                var newDeserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(this.Json);
                if (newDeserializeObject.Results != null)
                {
                    rootObject.Results.AddRange(newDeserializeObject.Results);
                }

                rootObject.Next = newDeserializeObject.Next;
            }

            return rootObject;
        }
    }
```

I know that if I use a block of code "using HttpClient", I will avoid the necessity of using the disposable. But, If I use that block code "using HttpClient" inside of a loop the way I´m doing above, the object that I´m creating will be reusable? Or it will be created, and disposable foreach time that the loop occours? The way I´m doing it could cause performance issues?

Comment: Ah, HttpClient. Though it's disposable, you really shouldn't be disposing it. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed and other similar information on the web

Comment: Thanks for the response. I´m asking that, because I was reading this article https://johnthiriet.com/efficient-api-calls/, and I got confused because on every example he´s using this (var client = new HttpClient()). So I didn´t get it the idea behind that

Comment: The problem is that experienced C# programmers see a class that implements `IDisposable` and know that they need to wrap instances in `using`. I don't know why HttpClient breaks this rule. I suspect that the design expectation was that it would be used like a SqlConnection instance, but after the interface was published, they realized that it worked better it it was managed more like a singleton

Comment: @Flydog57 well, yes, `IDisposable` have to be disposed, but question is when. For Web API, that is using `HttpClient` in the controller methods, `HttpClient` should be disponsed only before service shut down.

Comment: @HeitorRibeiro for Net.Core 2.1 and above you could use `IHttpClientFactory` to deal with HttpClients. Please, see this article for more details: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore

Comment: @alexandergoldabin: thanks! That's a very interesting read. Time to update our dev standards yet again

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin thanks for the article. I didn´t know about the new interface available, and why we should use that. It´s really good to update our standards

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin The article that you passed really helped me on my question about the disposable. Thanks a lot for that. If you want, post as the answer of this question, and I will mark as the right one. Sorry for the late response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering particular question: you don't need to dispose your `HttpClient`, neither in while loop, nor in the whole request method. Since your application performing requests to external API using `HttpClient`, then `HttpClient` need to be disposed only when your application shuts down.

For **NET Core 2.1** and above there's a useful abstraction called `HttpClientFactory` that creates and manages pool of `HttpClient`s for you. You need just to register it in DI Container:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Registering IHttpClientFactory
    services.AddHttpClient();
    // ...
}
```

...and inject in your class:

```
public class RequestToSwapiApi
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public RequestToSwapiApi(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<RootObject> ReturnTheStarShipModels()
    {
        HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        //...
```

For more information:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore