# async Task<string> returns 'string' does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, .net

My update **Update.Check()** method throws this error: `'string' does not contain a definition for 'Get'`.

Googled for hours, but couldn't figure it out.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyTestProgram
{
    public class Update
    {
        public static void Check()
        {
            string result = Task.FromResult(string.Get.Result);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        private static async Task<string> Get()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            return await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost/?update=val");
        }
    }
}
```

Using `.NET Framework 4.5`

Comment: It refers to this part: `(string.Get.Result)`

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error message says. What's the question?

Comment: Also, please don't use HttpClient like that in production code - you could run into port exhaustion problems.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica: do you mean that HttpClient should only be "instantiated once per application" as well as try{} catch{}?

Comment: @AlexG Nope, not only one instace. But either a try finally or a using, to actually dispose of it after use. Networking stuff on principle contains unamanged resources.

Comment: Not according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed-between-requests

Comment: @Christopher No, you shouldn't dispose of HttpClient instance, you should use a single instance (except in ASP.NET Core, which has a factory for that purpose). Even disposing of it doesn't completely protect you from port exhaustion.

Comment: @Christopher Please see [this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx) as well as [this very thorough Microsoft-endorsed blog post](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) on why you should never use `HttpClient` in a `using` block. The short answer is that calling `Dispose()` will *not* actually clean up all of its unmanaged resources (see the blog post for more details on that point), so if you're using `HttpClient` heavily even a `using` block won't prevent port exhaustion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line:

```
(string.Get.Result)
```

string has no property called Get. It has a bunch of functions starting with Get, but not a pure get. I honestly I have no idea why you wrote the string type in that place.

My best guess is that you wanted `(Get().Result)`? `Task<T>` has a Result property and `Get()` returns a `Task<string>`. The closest thing to something sensible.

[Task.FromResult()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult) is a generic function. So you would have to call it with `Task.FromResult<string>()`. But that would mean you take a `Task<string>`, extract it's result, then put that result back into another, unrelated `Task<string>`.

Wich brings me to maybe this being the intention:

```
string result = Get().Result;
```

Comment: That's right, I was already returning a Task.

Comment: @AlexG was `string result = Get().Result;` the droid you were looking for?