# Fix this implementation of 'IDisposable' to conform to the dispose pattern

Tags: c#

I have this working code here which is to download a file with progress. When I run SonarScanner, it complaints that I should consider to

> Fix this implementation of 'IDisposable' to conform to the dispose pattern.

```
public class HttpClientDownloadWithProgress : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _downloadUrl;
    private readonly string _destinationFilePath;
    private readonly string _username;
    private readonly string _password;
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    
    public delegate Task ProgressChangedHandler(long? totalFileSize, long totalBytesDownloaded, double? progressPercentage, string fileName);

    public event ProgressChangedHandler ProgressChanged;

    public HttpClientDownloadWithProgress(string downloadUrl, string destinationFilePath, string username, string password)
    {
        _downloadUrl = downloadUrl;
        _destinationFilePath = destinationFilePath;
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }

    public async Task StartDownload()
    {            
        _httpClient = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1) };

        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_username}:{_password}");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

        using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_downloadUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)) {
            await DownloadFileFromHttpResponseMessage(response);
        }
            
    }

    private async Task DownloadFileFromHttpResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var totalBytes = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

        using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()) {
            await ProcessContentStream(totalBytes, contentStream);
        }
        
    }

    private async Task ProcessContentStream(long? totalDownloadSize, Stream contentStream)
    {
        var totalBytesRead = 0L;
        var readCount = 0L;
        var buffer = new byte[8192];
        var isMoreToRead = true;

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_destinationFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 8192, true))
        {
            do
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(_destinationFilePath);

                var bytesRead = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    isMoreToRead = false;
                    await TriggerProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead, fileName);
                    continue;
                }

                await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                readCount += 1;

                if (readCount % 100 == 0) {
                    // change status to "DOWNLOADED"
                    await TriggerProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead, fileName);
                }
                // change status to "DOWNLOADING"
            }
            while (isMoreToRead);
        }
    }

    private async Task TriggerProgressChanged(long? totalDownloadSize, long totalBytesRead, string fileName)
    {
        if (ProgressChanged == null)
            return;

        double? progressPercentage = null;
        if (totalDownloadSize.HasValue)
            progressPercentage = Math.Round((double)totalBytesRead / totalDownloadSize.Value * 100, 2);

        await ProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead, progressPercentage, fileName);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _httpClient?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my `Dispose()` method? How can I implement the dispose pattern?

Comment: Do you really want to dispose the httpClient? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed-between-requests#:~:text=Although%20HttpClient%20does%20indirectly%20implement,needs%20to%20make%20HTTP%20requests.

Comment: I'd also recommend [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Have you read the MS docs that describe the [Dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)? Note that your class is not `sealed` currently, so you're being encouraged to use the pattern that supports derived types.

Comment: I don't know SonarScanner but based on ReSharper and [FxCop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1063) the warning should go away if you make your class sealed or if you create a `protected virtual Dispose(bool)` method so the derived classes can also dispose their resources correctly

Comment: After I set to `sealed`, the warning does go away. THanks.

Comment: It sounds like [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) request to me, rather than a concise question for StackOverflow.

Comment: A quick glance, and I'm puzzled why the HttpClient isn't just a local variable in a using within StartDownload.

Comment: @BentTranberg It actually should be injected and _not_ disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Some older linters like the pattern to be:

1. Implement `IDisposable` and forward the call to `Dispose(true)`
2. Implement a finalizer that forwards to `Dispose(false)`
3. Add a `virtual protected void Dispose(bool disposing)` method doing the actual disposal of resources based on whether the call originates from the finalizer or the destructor.

This ensures that the GC finalizer thread gets a chance to clear of unmanaged resources if any.

Something along these lines

```cs
protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if(disposing){
       _httpClient?.Dispose();
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this); // no need to run the finalizer we have dispose everything we need
    }
   
}

public void Dispose()=>Disposing(true);

public ~HttpClientDownloadWithProgress()=>Disposing(false);
}
```

But in your case it's doubtful that inheritance would be the way forward. I'd rather compose an `HttpClient` and a `Progress` and keep the client alive longer so other composites may use it.

Comment: 2 is only needed if you have unmanaged resources. Which, nowadays, is basically never. So, in your code, for example, the finalizer should definitely be removed.

Comment: Absolutely @mjwillis, but some linters will moan about it - including OP's. Hence the 'old-school' IDisposable implementation.

Comment: Which linter forces you to add a pointless finalizer?