# How to download a file from an URL to a server folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am working on an ASP.NET Core web app and I'm using Razor Pages.

I have some URLs displayed in my app and when I click on one of them, I want to download the file corresponding to that URL on a folder on the server where the application is stored, not on the client.

This is important because the file needs to be processed server-side by some other third-party applications.

The URLs along with other metadata are coming from a database and I created a DB context to load them. I made a CSS HTML file and displayed the information in a form. When I click on a button, I post the URL to a method handler.

I receive the URL in the method but I don't know how to download that file on the server without downloading it first on the client and then saving/uploading it to the server. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Post the code you have

Comment: It's just an OnPost method that receives a url parameter. I don't know how to download the file from that url on the server instead of the client. I tried messing a bit with HttpWebRequest but I didn't manage to do what I wanted.

Comment: I'm sure SO is full of "how do I download a file in c#" posts you can give a go at. I'd ignore the "it's on a server" part to start with.. just get a console app download working then port the code

Comment: the "it's on a server" part is the most important part..the app works fine if I'm using it on my local machine, but I plan on using it from my phone and I need to download the files on the server, not on my phone

Comment: Where did I tell you to download a file on your phone? What phone do you have that runs c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can use System.Net.WebClient

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient ())
{
    Client.DownloadFile (
            // Param1 = Link of file
            new System.Uri("Given URL"),
            // Param2 = Path to save
            "On SERVER PATH"
        );
}
```

Comment: this worked fine but I used DownloadFileAsync..either way..seems to get the job done..thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 9):

Starting .NET 6 `WebRequest`, `WebClient`, and `ServicePoint` classes [are deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated).

To download a file using the recommended `HttpClient` instead, you'd do something like this:

```cs
// using System.Net.Http;
// using System.IO;

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var responseStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(requestUrl);
using var fileStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create);
responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

Remember to not use `using`, and to not dispose the `HttpClient` instance after every use. More context [here](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed-between-requests).

The [recommended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to acquire a `HttpClient` instance is to get it from `IHttpClientFactory`. If you get an `HttpClient` instance using a `HttpClientFactory`, you may dispose the `HttpClient` instance after every use.