# Making API calls between two APIs in the same docker compose

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, docker-compose

I have a solution in .NET with a main API, and other secondary APIs, I want to make API calls from the main API to the others.
The solution is dockerized.

Docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  acmeapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}acmeapi
    container_name: acmeapi
    environment:
        JWT_SECRET: "LoremIpsumisimplydummytextofasab"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AcmeAPI/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "14331:443"

  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - "14330:1433"
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Abc*123!
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    volumes:
      - sqlserver-data:/var/opt/mssql


  mocktarjeta:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mocktarjeta
    container_name: mocktarjeta
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MockTarjeta/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "14332:443"
      - "1234:80"
  
    


  mockfactura:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mockfactura
    container_name: mockfactura
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MockFactura/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "14333:443"
   

  mockenvio:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mockenvio
    container_name: mockenvio
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MockEnvio/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "14334:443"
   
  
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes  # Habilita el archivo AOF
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
   
volumes:
  sqlserver-data:
  redis-data:
```

`acmeapi` is my main API.
`mocktarjeta`, `mockfactura` and `mockenvio` are the secondary APIs.

Here I'm trying to make a request from `acmeapi` to `mocktarjeta`.

```
public async Task<StatusDTO> mockTarjetaAsync(string numeroTarjeta)
{
    
    string apiUrl = "http://mocktarjeta:80/api/Tarjeta"; 

    // Crear una instancia de HttpClient
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
           
            var postData = new
            {
                tarjetaNumero = numeroTarjeta
            };

           
            string jsonContent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);

           
            var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

          
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);

           
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                
                return new StatusDTO(true, "worked");
            }
            else
            {
                return new StatusDTO(false, "didnt work");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new StatusDTO(false, "Se produjo una excepción: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This code ends in an exception:

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (mocktarjeta:14332)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

For some reason it makes the request to the port 14332, which is the port for outside the docker network instead of doing it to the specified url:  "http://mocktarjeta:80/api/Tarjeta"

I tried creating a network in the docker-compose file but it didn't work or I did it wrongly.

Comment: the standard port number for SQL Server is 1433.  So it looks like you may have two SQL Servers at different ports.  Port 80 is the standard port for HTTP.  So it looks like your front end should be an http connection on port 80.  The backend is a connection from the server to a SQL Server database.

Comment: Side note, if you are expecting this application/endpoint to see any significant amount of traffic, then you'll want to reconsider how you are using `HttpClient`. The short story is that creating and disposing many instances of `HttpClient` in a short amount of time can lead to socket exhaustion on the host machine. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed-between-requests) (and its answers) do a good job of explaining the details.