# Should RestClient of Restsharp be singleton and never disposed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, httpclient, restsharp

Restsharp documentation states "RestSharp is a wrapper around HttpClient".

Now, as it states in [Do HttpClient and HttpClientHandler have to be disposed between requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed-between-requests?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) "the general consensus is that you do not (should not) need to dispose of HttpClient."

So is it right that the Restclient should be singleton and never disposed, so it can live through the whole app life?

Just want the right approach in that case.

Comment: Just use c# HttpClient. How you dispose of it depends on the version of .Net.

Comment: Don'\t use RestSharp and you won't need to worry about this. Restsharp is awful.