How can I know which IDisposable classes I need to dispose?
Sounds like an odd question: my received wisdom was that if something implemented IDisposable then it always needed to be disposed.  I was therefore looking for some kind of analyzer warning that would tell me any time I forgot to do so.  But then I came across this answer which states that "you do not always want to Dispose objects [which implement IDisposable]", and seeing as how Task implements IDisposable and yet I don't think I've ever seen an example of a Task being disposed, this does indeed seem to be true.  There's also IHost which is usually not disposed explicitly, as well as ScrollableControl in Windows forms.
This seems to blow previous advice about IDisposable out of the water: now, you don't know whether you need to dispose of an class instance even if it implements IDisposable.  How can you know?  Is it just a case of having to read all the documentation and hope that the author remembered to mention whether or not you need to dispose the thing?  A secondary question is why Task implements that interface if it doesn't usually need disposal.  Why not create a new IOptionalDisposable interface or something to avoid this mess?
Note: I'm aware that there are some other questions that seem to make this one a dupe but I think they're actually out of date.  Task has come into common usage since they were asked and answered.

I'd go with the "dispose everything that is disposable"-pattern. Even if you won't need it in some cases, it shouldn't hurt. Relying on that would imply internal (hidden) knowledge you usually don't have.

I'd suggest removing "Why not create a new IOptionalDisposable interface or something to avoid this mess?" or rephrasing it to clarify what kind of answer you are expecting. "Why something isn't implemented" isn't really answerable.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Yeah, unfortunately that makes code very noisy with a ton of usings and try/finallys all over the place.  It's also very easy to forget to do.  Frankly I think far too many things implement IDisposable.

As for Task, the Docs explictly explain why it does implement IDisposable and that you usually don't need to dispose of them and even links to a longer article about this :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.dispose?view=net-9.0#system-threading-tasks-task-dispose

@Fildor sounds to me that MS realized they're breaking there own rules and decided to not dipose tasks any more, except for some really rare usages of WaitHandle. They also mentioned disposing the task leave it usable (except for the prementioned case). So you now can dispose a task without any danger.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain It really was a bumpy start with Task and I think it will still drag trails here or there for quite some time. But honestly: it's somewhat soothing to see that I am not the only one regretting my code from last year.

a classic example is the HttpClient that as far as I know should not be a "use and dispose immediately" (keeping the same object for a long time is expected , pooling mechanisms implemented etc... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed-between-requests#15708633). I'd go for "use the idisposable using always by default", and educate yourself and collleague for some precise exceptions (like HttpClient)

Use the using declarations introduced in C# 8.0: using var resource = new Resource();. They do not add a nesting level. The only thing you need to do is to add the keyword using in front of variable declarations.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Which, if you're having to do it for every single task, is very noisy.  Every second word is going to be using.  And it doesn't work for nullable reference types that you might assign, and therefore you need to wrap everything in a try/finally block and Dispose in the finally.

" if you're having to do it for every single task" - which we already established that you don't.

using var also works with nullable reference types. See: https://sharplab.io/#gist:3719c8fb69182bbd8d494c26bc4b08a0

Yeah, but you have to shift the logic that creates it out into a method.  I often have it in an if/else clause following the variable declaration.

There is no such thing as an optional disposable. The question rather is: Who is responsible for disposing of the resource?
Even when there is a finalizer that does it, I think the finalizer is more like a safety net, but you should dispose as soon as possible.

This question is similar to: How do i know when i need to dispose an object?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The appropriate thing when you find an existing question is not to re-ask it but post a bounty asking for new answers. At nearly 30,000 reputation even a 500-rep bounty should be of no consequence to you.



How can I know which IDisposable classes I need to dispose?


I would argue that this depends on the ownership of the disposable instance. Prime example would be IDisposable's created by the default DI container which handles the dispose (see Does .NET Core IServiceScopeFactory child scope dispose transient services?, Object disposed problem in caching scenario for example). So for scoped/singleton services it is dangerous to dispose an instance since it can be used by multiple "clients".
Another example of ownership is the StreamWriter with it's leaveOpen ctor parameter. By default the disposable stream ownership is transferred to the StreamWriter and it will dispose the stream, but this can be changed by manipulating this parameter (true to leave the stream open after the StreamWriter object is disposed; otherwise, false.)
Since .NET have no concept of borrow checker like Rust does (which solves kind of a similar problem) there is no way to enforce this in a type-safe way, so this depends on your understanding of the code base.


and seeing as how Task implements IDisposable and yet I don't think I've ever seen an example of a Task being disposed


This is a bit of legacy issue, nowadays you should not dispose tasks in 99,(9%) of cases, more on the topic can be found in this article by Stephen Toub, which has the following quote:

In .NET 4, the WaitHandle was lazily-initialized in a few situations: if the Task’s ((IAsyncResult)task).AsyncWaitHandle explicitly-implemented interface property was accessed, or if the Task was used as part of a Task.WaitAll or Task.WaitAny call and the Task was not yet completed.  This made the answer to the “should I dispose” question slightly difficult, as if you had a lot of tasks being used with WaitAll/WaitAny, it might actually have been good to dispose of those tasks.

See also:

C# Dependency between classes and IDisposable


Another one: most IDbCommand implementations do not need to be disposed (connections absolutely MUST). It's legacy from ADO COM, but the newer -- HA! 20 years old now -- command objects for ADO.Net are generally safe to leave alone. (This is based on an interaction I had with an MS employee years back, so unfortunately no real documentation for this, though).

Yeah Task is "a bit of a legacy issue" but it's a really sucky one because it now prevents you from being able to assume that IDisposable should actually be disposed (as well as the other issues you mentioned).  "Understanding of the code base" sounds about right, which is surely an issue for C# to overcome because you can't expect devs to read through the code base of everything they use!

@Jez "you can't expect devs to read through the code base of everything they use!" - totally agree. Personally I usually follow this set of "rules": 1) dispose everything you create unless you  are "giving it away" (i.e. in factories and similar) 2) conventions-conventions-conventions 3) not sure if you should dispose - dispose (ObjectDisposedException will tell when you should not)

If the class is the sole deciding factor which IDisposable instances you need to dispose, then it is all such classes. Even if you check the existing implementations of such classes whether they contain any unmanaged resources and find none, that is still not a sufficient argument ‒ the implementation may change at any point, and there is nothing to gain optimization-wise to remove an empty Dispose call. Even MemoryStream.Dispose has its uses ‒ it prevents code to write to it, and it suppresses the finalizer, which may even improve the performance in some situations.
Instead, the deciding factor is whether you own the instance up to the point of Dispose, and there are no other users whom you'd want to share it with. Sometimes, deterministic cleanup is not worth it ‒ if you can't accurately track which object is being owned by whom, or you cannot assess whether there are any other consumers of it, just leave it up to the GC, that's its job. But when you construct a disposable class yourself, use it throughout a single scope, and can easily say no other code is to use it thereafter, then I'd argue you should absolutely dispose it. Of course there are some tricks like RefCountDisposable, but they are not needed in the vast majority of situations.
If we are talking about tasks specifically, the same rules apply ‒ in most situations, you should not own any task you obtain from arbitrary methods. Such tasks may be pre-cached and hence shared, and you really should not be disposing them if that is the case. async methods give you a task to observe, not to manipulate with.
