# Using HttpClient to make a call within a Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient, webapi

I've been working on a .NET 4.6.1 Web API project.  As part of this project, I need to call another Web API and I want to use the HttpClient to do so.

From my research online, you can't rely on just doing a normal HttpClient within a using clause as it doesn't garbage collect correctly and can lead to memory leaks.

E.g., I'm currently using it as follows:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CONTENTFUL_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS) } )
{
    responseText = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext:false);
}
```

But as suggested in other articles from Stack Overflow and others, this leads to memory leaks, and the way around this is to share a single instance of the HttpClient.
E.g., check [HTTPCLIENT DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [HttpClientHandler/HttpClient Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732546/httpclienthandler-httpclient-memory-leak).

I'm not sure however how to setup a shared "single" instance of the HttpClient from within an WebAPI itself?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on how to implement singleton pattern. Refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Then you can create a singleton of `HttpClient` and make it responsible for all `HTTP` calls from your API.